# On the analytic branch of $\text{Log}\,z$ in a simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ be a simply connected domain. It is a well-known conclusion that there exists an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $e^{f(z)} = z$. However, if $D$ contains a part of negative real axis (e.g., $D = \{z\mid \Re (z) \leq -1\}$), $\text{Log}\,z$ is not analytic on the negative real axis, hence cannot be analytic in $D$. How to explain this elegantly? $f(z) = \int_{-1}^z \frac{1}{w}dw - i\pi$ is a choice of $f(z)$, what is the relationship between $f(z)$ and $\text{Log}(z)$?

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your comment! But it is too abstract for me, would you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Which part? For each connected open $U\subset D$ contained in $\Bbb{C}-e^{it}[0,\infty)$ for some $t$ there is a branch of $\log$ analytic on $U$ and the other ones are obtained by adding $2i\pi k$. So the problem is to show that for $D$ simply connected those local branches glue to a branch analytic on $D$. Saying that $f(z)=\int_{z_0}^z \frac1s ds$ doesn't depend on the chosen path $z_0\to z\subset D$ is probably the simplest way.